# Azure devops cli : az devops security group membership list

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to use az devops security group membership list --id descriptor.
When I am using this cli I am getting the below error for one of my descriptor:
ERROR: TF400049: The request was aborted because it contained too many requested items 800, maximum allowed is 500.

I checked for continuation token as well but it seems like this cli doesnot support the continuation token.

Comment: Can you please add the command as you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure devops cli : az devops security group membership list

According to the document [az devops security group membership list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/group/membership?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-security-group-membership-list-optional-parameters):

Optional Parameters:

> - --detect
> - --org --organization
> - --relationship
> - --subscription
> - --debug
> - --help -h
> - --only-show-errors
> - --output -o
> - --query
> - --verbose

There is no such parameter to allow us to list all the users. You could add the user voice on the Github https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli.

Or you could try to use the REST API with continuation token to get all the users:

[Memberships - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/memberships/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a JMESQuery with --query to selectively get the results.